# Unpack a single element from a list of lists python

Tags: python, list, unpack

I have zipped some data into as following:

```
list1 = [1,33,3]
list2 = [2,44,23]
list3 = [[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,3],[4,5,3,1]]
list4 = [4,34,4]

data = [list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)]
```

However, list3 is a list of lists. So the output ended up being

```
[[1,2,[3,4,5,6],4],
 [33,44,[3,4,5,3],34], 
 [3,23,[4,5,3,1],4]]
```

I would like to unpack the list inside the lists like the following:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,4],
 [33,44,3,4,5,3,34], 
 [3,23,4,5,3,1,4]]
```

What is the best way to do that in python?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide sample data for all lists for us to replicate.

Comment: transpose the data using `list1, list2, list3, list4=list(zip(*data))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only two level-deep, you can try with first principles:

```py
out = [
    [e for x in grp for e in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
    for grp in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)
]

>>> out
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4], [33, 44, 3, 4, 5, 3, 34], [3, 23, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Exploring concepts

First, we have to know what we should do.

The problem is only because `list3` is a nested `list` and this is causing us problems.
To come up with a solution we have to think on how to turn list3 from a nested to a normal `list`.

> To point out:
>
> - the shape of `list3` is well-defined and it's always the same.
> - list3 is nested hence we have to think methods to flatten the list.

Finally I come up with 2 possible methods

---

#### Flattening `list3`

I would suggest to flatten `list3`, using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
chain.from_iterable(iterable)
```

> Alternate constructor for chain(). Gets chained inputs from a single iterable argument that is evaluated lazily.

this can flatten a list of lists.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import itertools
list1 = [1,33,3]
list2 = [2,44,23]
list3 = [[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,3],[4,5,3,1]]
list4 = [4,34,4]
flat_list3 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(list3)
data = [list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)]
>>> [[1,2,3,4,5,6,4],
     [33,44,3,4,5,3,34], 
     [3,23,4,5,3,1,4]]
```

---

### Deep nested list flatten

**NOTE**: This possibility is slower and applicable for nested lists that aren't of a particular shape.

You could use the [`deepflatten`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/deepflatten.html) with the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) builtin function.

Here is the equivalent to the defined function and arguments.

```
deepflatten(iterable, depth=None, types=None, ignore=None)
```

From the docs:

> Flatten an iterable with given depth.

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import deepflatten
>>> data = [[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, 6], 4], [33, 44, [3, 4, 5, 3], 34], [3, 23, [4, 5, 3, 1], 4]]
>>> list(map(lambda x:list(deepflatten(x)),data))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4], [33, 44, 3, 4, 5, 3, 34], [3, 23, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4]]
```

### Useful links:

1. [SO(ans) how to find lenght of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133008/13285707)
2. [make a flat list out of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/13285707)